# How features scaling for training and classification?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, scaling

I'm using SVM for data classification. I've scaled the training data using the formula (x-mean)/(standard deviation), but I do not know how to scaling new data to classify. 
Then I need to know, which mean and standard deviation I can using for these data? that is, I use its own mean and standard deviation (of the classification data) or I use the mean and standard deviation of training data for each component of the vector.

Comment: Reuse the old parameters. You can check scikit-learns StandardScaler (which is one fitted on the training-data, then reused) if you are fluent in python.

Comment: as Sascha said: Use the mean and deviation of the training data

Comment: thank for your answer.